# How to disable a button tag with type submit using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, submit

Can someone help me figure out how to disable a button tag, with type submit, when a form is submitted? Everything I find is showing me how to disable an input tag with type submit.

What I currently have is:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="addBookingForm.php" id="addBookingForm" name="addBookingForm" class="form-horizontal">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="addBooking" name="addBooking" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Booking</button>
```

Jquery:

```
    $('#addBookingForm').on('submit', function() {
        $("#addBooking").attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
    });
```

OR:

```
 onsubmit="document.getElementById('addBooking').disabled = 1;"
```

The problem with this is that it does not submit the page. The easiest solution would be to convert the button to be an input but I was hoping it could be done as a button

Many thanks!

Comment: `The problem with this is that it does not submit the page.` Which browser?

Comment: It happens in both firefox and chrome, I haven't tested anything else

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/mbje4bd0/1 and the form is submit. Have you checked the console for errors elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Ya works for me too so your issue is somewhere else

Comment: Thanks guys, you are right. I found the issue and it was some where else. very embarrassed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<form method="post" action="addBookingForm.php" id="addBookingForm" name="addBookingForm" class="form-horizontal">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addBooking").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
</script>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="addBooking" name="addBooking" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Booking</button>
</form>
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery solution, add the '(this).submit();' line BEFORE the line u use to disable the button

Comment: I guess you mean `$(this).submit();` but then it will trigger in loop same handler again and again and again... Maybe `this.submit();` instead but anyway OP's code should work as it is